# How to get the id of canvas item?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

If I store the canvas item in a variable I expect that is stored as an tkinter.rectangle object which I can use later.

```
rec = can.create_rectangle(l, fill="blue")
```

But instead is stored as an integer << class 'int' >>

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button

def press(canv, rect):
    print("pressed")
    canv.move(rect, 10)

l = [50,100,100,200]

root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root)
can.pack()
rec = can.create_rectangle(l, fill="blue")
print("rec",rec)    #1
print("type(rec) ", type(rec)) #<class 'int'>
b = Button(root, text="NOTHING", command=lambda:press(can, rec))
b.pack()
print("type(b) = ",type(b)) #<class 'tkinter.Button'>
print("b = ",b) #TCL id like .41549040
root.mainloop()
```

When run this code it returns a error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".21823184 move tagOrId xAmount yAmount"
```

Why is it of type integer and how get the id of the canvas item to move it around later?

Comment: ***`_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args:`***: You are misguided, it's not about `rec`. Read about the paramter of the [Tkinter.Canvas.move-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method)

Comment: What does that mean it's not about rec?

Comment: The `_tkinter.TclError:` is not about `rec` it's about missing parameter `x_move` and `y_move`

Comment: Ok now it makes sense to me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I store the canvas item in a variable I expect that is stored as an tkinter.rectangle object

That is a false expectation. The documented behavior is that it returns an integer id.

> Why is it of type integer and how get the id of the canvas item to move it around later?

There is no other id than the integer returned by the `create_rectangle` method. You can use this id to move the item around.

> When run this code it returns a error: `_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".21823184 move tagOrId xAmount yAmount"`

That error message is telling you exactly what is wrong: `wrong # args`. You must supply the id, and an xAmount and yAmount. You are only giving the id and the xAmount.

Comment: do you know why I get a ban for asking further questions? Or why was this question bad so that I know for improving my further questions?

Comment: @Module_art: I have no idea why. This question seems OK to me.

Comment: Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy: you don't give the Y value to function.
The function wants:

```
canv.move(item, x, y)
```

If you need to move its only on the x axis, you have to write the following string:

```
canv.move(rect, 10, 0)
```